# Why 4-byte alignment of width of bitmap is need?

Tags: bitmap, alignment

I cannot figure out why image width must be a multiple of 4 Byte.
Calculating the size of a bitmap is not difficult:

```
biSizeImage = ((((biWidth * biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3) * biHeight
```

The crazy roundoffs and shifts account for the bitmap being
DWORD-aligned at the end of every scanline.

After lots of searching, I found this formula from [This  Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms969901(v=msdn.10)) However, I still cannot understand why dword-alignment is necessary.
Can anyone help? Does this related to memory alignment?

Answer (score 2):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

> Padding bytes (not necessarily 0) must be appended to the end of the rows in order to bring up the length of the rows to a multiple of four bytes. When the pixel array is loaded into memory, each row must begin at a memory address that is a multiple of 4. This address/offset restriction is mandatory only for Pixel Arrays loaded in memory. For file storage purposes, only the size of each row must be a multiple of 4 bytes while the file offset can be arbitrary.[5] A 24-bit bitmap with Width=1, would have 3 bytes of data per row (blue, green, red) and 1 byte of padding, while Width=2 would have 6 bytes of data and 2 bytes of padding, Width=3 would have 9 bytes of data and 3 bytes of padding, and Width=4 would have 12 bytes of data and no padding.

Answer (score 1):

This was done as part of optimization for DIB drawing to ensure that every scanline is aligned.

> The CPU in modern computer hardware performs reads and writes to memory most efficiently when the data is naturally aligned, which generally means that the data's memory address is a multiple of the data size. For instance, in a 32-bit architecture, the data may be aligned if the data is stored in four consecutive bytes and the first byte lies on a 4-byte boundary.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Allocating_memory_aligned_to_cache_lines

It was introduced in Windows 3.0 (1990) when native 32-bit i486 processors was adopted. In previous Windows versions there was 16-bit bitmap scan line aligment used. You can still see 16-bit aligment in old APIs like [CreateBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createbitmap).